# Android SnackBar animations and FAB gets stuck

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar, floating-action-button

I am trying to implement a snackbar and a floating action button to move together. On my Nexus 6P emulator it works perfectly but when I use my actual Moto X (2014) device the snackbar has no animation (it just appears there) and the fab moves up but never comes down. Does anyone know what could be going wrong on just certain devices? (and yes I have animations on in developer settings)

This is what the snackbar code looks like.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(fab, "Removed " + positions.size() + " Task(s)", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! I had to anchor it to a child of the coordinator layout.

[View can not be anchored to the the parent CoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843705/view-can-not-be-anchored-to-the-the-parent-coordinatorlayout)